# R - use if statement to regroup variable

Tags: r

I want to regroup a variable into a new one.

If value is 0, new one should be 0 too.
If value ist 999, then make it missing, NA.
Everything else 1

This is my try:

```
id <- 1:10
variable <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,999,999)
df <- data.frame(id,variable)

df$variable2 <- 
  if (df$variable == 0) {
    df$variable2 = 0
  } else if (df$variable == 999){
    df$variable2 = NA
  } else {
    df$variable2 = 1
  }
```

And this the error message:

> In if (df$variable == 0) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only
>   the first element will be used

A pretty basic question but I'm a basic user. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ifelse`

```
df$variable2 <- ifelse(df$variable == 999, NA, ifelse(df$variable > 0, 1, 0))
df
#   id variable variable2
#1   1        0         0
#2   2        0         0
#3   3        0         0
#4   4        1         1
#5   5        2         1
#6   6        3         1
#7   7        4         1
#8   8        5         1
#9   9      999        NA
#10 10      999        NA
```

---

When you do `df$variable == 0` the output / `condition` is

```
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

where it should be a length-one logical vector that is not NA in `if(condition)`, see `?"if"`.

---

You can avoid `ifelse`, for example, like so

```
df$variable2 <- df$variable
df$variable2[df$variable2 == 999] <- NA
df$variable2[df$variable2 > 0] <- 1
```

Comment: With `ifelse` I had quite some bad experiences. Especially in combination with dataframe columns. It can behave very unintuitively. (`ifelse` is NOT simply a vectorized `if - else`. Definitely not. Thus - ) In my opinion one should always discourage (especially beginners) to use `ifelse` but rather try to find a solution with normal `if - else` clauses.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Thanks for the comment. Posted a second solution to avoid `ifelse`.

Comment: welcome! Yes, your second solution is much more R-ish. I am trying to find the link for a negative `ifelse` example - but difficult to find ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim ... Please do find such a link. To date, I have never any issue with `ifelse()`. Pass in it a vector to return a modified vector of same length!

Comment: @Parfait I couldn't find a link but added to my answer an example. You are right, using `ifelse` purely with vectors might not give any problems. But very often beginners and intermediates whish to use it on data frames. Choosing a column from data frame should give the same behaviour like choosing a vector. But it doesn't. See my example.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to avoid the if/else statement all together by using conditional statements within subset notation:

when `df$variable` is equal to zero, change it to zero

```
df$variable[df$variable==0] <- 0
```

when `df$variable` is equal to 999, change it to NA

```
df$variable[df$variable==999] <- NA
```

when `df$variable` is greater than 0 and is not equal to NA, change it to 1

```
df$variable[df$variable>0 & is.na(df$variable) == 'FALSE'] <- 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to recode your variable. You can do this (and other data/variable transformations) with the [sjmisc-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/), in your case with the `rec()`-command:

```
id <- 1:10
variable <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,999,999)
df <- data.frame(id,variable)

library(sjmisc)
rec(df, variable, rec = c("0=0;999=NA;else=1"))
#>    id variable variable_r
#> 1   1        0          0
#> 2   2        0          0
#> 3   3        0          0
#> 4   4        1          1
#> 5   5        2          1
#> 6   6        3          1
#> 7   7        4          1
#> 8   8        5          1
#> 9   9      999         NA
#> 10 10      999         NA

# or a single vector as input
rec(df$variable, rec = c("0=0;999=NA;else=1"))
#> [1]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA
```

There are many examples, also in the [help-file](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/rec.html), and you can find a sjmisc-cheatsheet at the [RStudio-Cheatsheet collection](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) (or [direct PDF-download here](http://strengejacke.de/sjmisc-cheatsheet.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

```
df$variable2 <- sapply(df$variable, 
                       function(el) if (el == 0) {0} else if (el == 999) {NA} else {1})
```

This one-liner reflects your:

> If value is 0, new one should be 0 too. If value ist 999, then make it
>   missing, NA. Everything else 1

Well, it is slightly slower than @markus's second or @SPJ's solutions which are most r-ish solutions.

**Why one should put away the hands from `ifelse`**

```
tt <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
b <- 1:4
ifelse(tt, a, b) ## [1] "a" "2" "c" "4"
# totally perfect and as expected!

df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=tt)
df$d <- ifelse(df$c, df$a, df$b)
## > df
##   a b     c d
## 1 a 1  TRUE 1
## 2 b 2 FALSE 2
## 3 c 3  TRUE 3
## 4 d 4 FALSE 4

######### This is wrong!! ##########################
## df$d is not [1] "a" "2" "c" "4"
## the problem is that 
## ifelse(df$c, df$a, df$b)
## returns for each TRUE or FALSE the entire
## df$a or df$b intead of treating it like a vector.
## Since the last df$c is FALSE, df$b is returned
## Thus we get df$b for df$d.
## Quite an unintuitive behaviour.
##
## If one uses purely vectors, ifelse is fine.
## But actually df$c, df$a, df$b should be treated each like a vector.
## However, `ifelse` does not.
## No warnings that using `ifelse` with them will lead to a 
## totally different behaviour.
## In my view, this is a design mistake of `ifelse`.
## Thus I decided myself to abandon `ifelse` from my set of R commands.
## To avoid that such kind of mistakes can ever happen.
#####################################################
```

As @Parfait pointed out correctly, it was a misinterpretation.
The problem was that df$a was treated in the data frame as a factor.

```
df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=tt, stringsAsFactor = F)
df$d <- ifelse(df$c, df$a, df$b)
df
```

Gives the correct result.

```
  a b     c d
1 a 1  TRUE a
2 b 2 FALSE 2
3 c 3  TRUE c
4 d 4 FALSE 4
```

Thank you @Parfait to pointing that out!
Strange that I didn't recognized that in my initial trials.
But yeah, you are absolutely right!

Comment: That's not an `ifelse` issue but a factor issue. Use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in `data.frame()` so column a is treated as character. This is a regular new useR overlook.

Comment: @Parfait - it would be nice but I tried stringsAsFactors = FALSE, but it is as I wrote here - you get entire df$b as df$d; I would have recognized a stringsAsFactors issue quite quickly. Because this is the first thing I assume when sth is wrong with data frames in R... - `df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=tt, stringsAsFactors = F)` and then `df$d <- ifelse(df$c, df$a, df$b)` - looks **exactly** the same like before - df$d is identical to df$b. And the explanation I already wrote above in the example. - And that is the point - even experienced users as you could not predict this behavior from code!

Comment: Hmmmm... I am unable to reproduce using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. See demo with resulting `df$d` exactly equal and identical to original `ifelse`: https://rextester.com/YGEL36294.

Comment: @Parfait Oh I did sth wrong before - it works. Strange - why it didn't work before.